# How to lazy evaluate merged observable, i.e. on click of button when using merge() (RxJs v6)?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have a merged stream of observables,

`const nextClickHandler$ = merge(doA$, doB$, doC$)`,

`do A$/B$/C$` are observables which makes HTTPRequests or performs some sideeffects, they operate on some mutually exclusive conditions, where either doA$/doB$/doC$ are active and perform the network calls / side-effects.

The use-case is, on the click of the next button, do either A/B/C, I am facing an issue on how to subscribe to this merged observable, if I subscribe to it before-click of next, i.e.

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.nextClickHandler$.subscribe()
}
```

This will be eagerly evaluating those mutually exclusive conditions and executing, without even clicking next,

I tried subscribing on click of goForward:

```
 goForward(): void {
        if (this.getCurrentStep() == 1) {
            if (this.validateForm()) {\
                //performs side-effects for either A$/B$/C$
                this.nextClickHandler$.subscribe();  
            }
            return;
        }
```

But now, when I am on the Step I again, it doesnt wait for the click of the next, since it is a long-living subscription, it just eagerly executes the behaviour, which is not what I want, I want them to be lazy-executed only when clicking next, I tried `take(1)` but that does not fix the issue, How can I achieve this?

Comment: Question: does it work when you place subscribe in `goForward()`?  So your issue is you want to cancel subscription when they go back?

Comment: I can definitely do so, when going back I can unsubscribe, it does work when I subscribe in `goForward()`, but is there a better way than managing the subscriptions manually, I don't like the idea of creating a subscription every time on the click of the next.

Comment: There is probably a better way.  It's hard to say without know more about your flow.  You could possibly have a `currentStep$` observable that internally uses `switchMap()` to subscibe to whatever observable is relevant to each step.  I can elaborate if you share more details / code.  If you could put it in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy), that would make it easier to help you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create an Observable from click event of the button, using [fromEvent](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent):

```
 <button #sbtn>
      Subscribe
    </button>

 @ViewChild('sbtn', { static: true }) sbtn: ElementRef;
 this.clickBtnEvent$ = fromEvent(this.sbtn.nativeElement, 'click');
```

and than on init (or after view init) you subscribe to that Observable:

```
this.clickBtnEvent$.pipe(
  mergeMap(() => nextClickHandler$)
).subscribe( /* some logic*/);
```

This Observable will emit only when you click the button, actualy every time you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

If creating multiple subscription variables is not something to your liking then,

`switchMap()` is a good example to use, but if you want to keep using `merge()` or `mergeMap`, try using `takeUntil()` operator. You need not create a subscription variable every time.

You create only once and destroy once, but you can use it many times in the same page code.

```
// Step-1: Create a destroy variable
destroy$: Subject<any> = new Subject();

// Step-2: Use it how many times you want

obs1$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe();
obs2$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe();
obs3$.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe();
.
.
.
so on... 

// Step-3 : Destroy the subject

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

If you want to merge observables, you can also use combineLatest() operator, where you can subscribe to multiple observables at once. Something like this:

```
combineLatest(obs1$, obs2$, obs3$)
   .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
   .subscribe(([obs1Data, obs2Data, obs3Data]) => {})
```